# Force mobile layout in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

Is there a way to always force the mobile layout using only CSS in Bootstrap responsive?

I think one way to do it would be to set @screen-sm to a really large number. But I'd rather not mess with LESS files, can I do it using only CSS?

Comment: please stop using "bootstrap" as tag. it's another thing.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a custom bootstrap build using their website. Here's my version: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id=52279502e4625826d93b

If anyone has a better way of doing this, please share.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use media query:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) and  (min-width: 360px) {}
```